# Google charts animation not working

Tags: animation, charts, onchange

The expected behaviour of the chart is to change and show a different series, when a different option gets selected from the drop down. While changing, it does not animate, even though i have included the "animate" element in the options. Following is my code:

jsfiddle.net/7C53q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem.  Finally, I tried re-using the same chart object for the second draw() call, and it worked.  It makes sense, when you think about it: how's it supposed to know what the original data was, unless you pass in the chart object drawn with it (or something else containing the original data)?

If you look in the animate example, they create one chart object, then do the draw() in two separate functions, without re-creating the chart object.  Please don't ask me why they don't mention this little fact.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I got it solved by calling another draw() in the same function. Can you tell me why they don't mention this fact? It is pretty important in animating the chart.

Comment: I said "please don't ask" because I have no idea.  It's kind of like teaching someone how to drive without mentioning how important it is to not hit other cars.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. That is a good analogy though. But, what if the instructions aren't laid out correctly in the driving manual (being google chart coding instructions)? The driver is sure to hit other cars. Only with an instructor he will be successful in driving without hitting any cars. I think they really should have mentioned it. Anyways, thanks for the help!!! I appreciate it.